# Property [ptitle] does not exist on this collection instance in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table with full of created products and when I click one of products' edit button, I get this error message: `Property [ptitle] does not exist on this collection instance (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\webshop\resources\views\admin\termekszerk.blade.php)`
Can anyone help me to solve this, please?
Models:

```
class Category extends Model 
{

protected $fillable = ['cid', 'cname'];
protected $primaryKey = 'cid';


 public function item() 
{   
    return $this->hasMany('App\Item', 'cid');
}
}

class Item extends Model
{
protected $fillable = ['pid', 'pcat', 'pdescription', 'ptitle', 'pdb', 'par', 'pcikkszam' ];
protected $primaryKey = 'pid';


public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'pcat');
}

}
```

Controller:

```
public function pedit($pid)
{
    $product = Item::find($pid)->first();
    return view('admin.termekszerk', compact('product'));
}


public function pupdate(ProductFormRequest $request, $pid)
{
    $product = Item::find($pid)->first();
    $product->ptitle = $request->get('ptitle');
    $product->pcat = $request->get('pcat');
    $product->pcikkszam = $request->get('pcikkszam');
    $product->par = $request->get('par');
    $product->pdb = $request->get('pdb');
    $product->pdescription = $request->get('pdescription');

    $product->save();
    return redirect(action('CategoriesController@index', $product->pid))->with('status', 'A termék frissítve!');

}
```

termekszerk blade (this is the page what does not show when I click before edit button):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="well well bs-component">

        <form class="form-horizontal" method="post">

            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <p class="alert alert-danger">{{ $error }}</p>
            @endforeach


            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{!! csrf_token() !!}">

            <fieldset>
                <legend>Termék szerkesztése</legend>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="title" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Termék neve</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ptitle" name="ptitle" value="{!! $product->ptitle !!}">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="title" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Cikkszám</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pcikkszam" name="pcikkszam" value="{!! $product->pcikkszam !!}">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="title" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Termék ára</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="par" name="par" value="{!! $product->par !!}">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="title" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Mennyiség</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pdb" name="pdb" value="{!! $product->pdb !!}">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="content" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Termék leírás</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="18" id="pdescription" name="pdescription">{!! $product->pdescription !!}</textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
                        <a href="/admin/create_products"><button class="btn btn-default pbtn">Mégsem</button></a>

                         <form method="post" action="{!! action('CategoriesController@pupdate', $product->pid) !!}">
                            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{!! csrf_token() !!}">

                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pbtn">Változtatás</button> 
                        </form>

                        <form method="post" action="{!! action('CategoriesController@pdestroy', $product->pid) !!}">
                            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{!! csrf_token() !!}">

                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger pull-right pbtn">Törlés</button>    
                        </form>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: replace ```{!! $product->ptitle !!}``` with ```{{ $product->ptitle }}``` and other field and let me know result i dont know why you use {!! every where in value

Comment: I changed everywhere and I still get the same error message

Comment: test My answer controller suggestion too

Comment: delete ```first()``` after ```find()``` I mean ```$product = Item::find($pid);``` and test it

Answer (score 0):

I saw some shouldn't in your codes maybe correcting them will solve your problem

first in your controller:

```
public function pedit($pid)
{
    $product = Item::find($pid)->first();
    return view('admin.termekszerk', compact('product'));
}
```

you use find method and I am not sure $pid is `PK` in your table structure

and you use first() method after find; its not needed because find method will get one row

for example if your table is like this

table:

-id (auto increamnet)

-pid

when you use find($pid) this search in id column and find just one row

so you can change your code like this:

```
public function pedit($pid)
{
    $product = Item::where('pid',$pid)->first();
    return view('admin.termekszerk', compact('product'));
}
```

**But If `pid` is `PK` in you table so you should remove `first()` method after find**

secound :

I dont know why you use `{!! !!}` in your blade

you should use `{{ }}` instead of that in your blade normally

but if you store data as HTML code you can use `{!! !!}` to get HTML codes

[Displaying Unescaped Data](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#displaying-data)

> By default, Blade {{ }} statements are automatically sent through
>   PHP's htmlspecialchars function to prevent XSS attacks. If you do not
>   want your data to be escaped, you may use the following syntax:

Comment: I tried this and there is the same error. The pid is auto increment and it is the primary key. I do not have another id. Maybe then I should add an new cloumn in my table.

Comment: I added a 'pslug' column which create an random product id number, and still write the same error. I do not understand why write that Property [ptitle] does not exist...all products have ptitle.

Comment: @Dodo I think it doesnt related to ptitle because if you remove ptitle input in blade you see secound data return error So your main problem is in pedit controller, Did you test with where condition instead of find like this: ```$product = Item::where('pid',$pid)->first();```?

Comment: check ```return $product->ptitle;``` in controller before return view or ```dd($product)``` in controller to know $product type and data

Comment: Finally, I solved it. I added this in AppServiceProvider.php:
    `public function boot()
     {
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);

        View::composer('*', function($view) {
            $view->with('categories', Category::latest()->get());
            $view->with('products', Item::latest()->get());
        });
    }`

Comment: hmmm. happy to you,But this is not solution to error that you wrote in question, it just send products and categories to all views ,

Answer (score 0):

If you have added "ptitle" later and your previous products in database are without ptitle then may be thats why it is causing error

Comment: all products have ptitle in database, that is why I do not understand where is the problem.